# How to insert a cmdlet into a string in powershell

Tags: string, powershell, variables, powershell-cmdlet

Say I want to tell the time in a string, just like this

```
Write-Output "It's now (Get-Date)"
```

That doesn't seem to work, as opposed to:

```
$time = Get-Date
Write-Output "It's now $time"
```

How can I achieve the same result without resourcing it to a variable?

Comment: $(get-Date)....

Answer (score 5):

Two ways I can think of off the top of my head. The first way is to use the subexpression - `$()` - operator:

```
Write-Host "It is now $(Get-Date)"
```

The second way is to use the string formatting - `-f` - operator:

```
Write-Host ("It is now {0}" -f (Get-Date))
```

Note that `Write-Host` will appear only in the host application and can't be redirected, so I generally don't recommend it unless you have a specific reason you don't want the command's output to be redirected.

The `-f` operator gives some flexibility for your outputting of the date. Example:

```
"It is now {0:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss}" -f (Get-Date)
```

See [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) for the details on the date formatting.

Answer (score 3):

You can format it by adding an additional `$` before the brackets, PowerShell will then parse that first:

```
Write-Output "It's now $(Get-Date)"
```

Answer (score -1):

`Write-Host "It's now" (Get-Date)`

Comment: The newline 9is not a problem according to the post. The issue is avoiding using a variable. So what you have posted would probalby be the answer without the -NoNewLine parameter. Also, Write host will take ny number of arguments and write them to the console separated by spaces so the last space in "It's now " is superfluous.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I agree, the -NoNewLine was not relevant to the question and the additional space is superfluous, I just wanted to provide an alternative answer with what I assumed was the formatting OP required. Not sure the downvote is justified though.

Comment: The code provided would not give the result that the OP wanted so by my definition is not the right answer. The good news is that you can edit the answer so that it would give the correct result then I could remove the down vote.